# Manifold of Lie subgroups

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group. Consider the space $\mathcal{H}$ of all Lie subgroups of $G$, i.e.,

$$\mathcal{H}:=\{ H \leq G \ : \ H \text{ is a Lie subgroup of } G\}$$

Is there a structure of (possibly infinite-dimensional) manifold on $\mathcal{H}$. Do you know a reference to study this structure?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer is trivially yes, i.e. the zero dimensional manifold. And if $\mathcal{H}$ is uncountable, then it can be turned into any manifold you want. But I assume you want this structure to be somehow related to $G$? If so, then how?

Comment: I assume that $G$ is a manifold of dimension larger than 1. So, $\mathcal{H}$ cannot be discrete (for any $g \in G$ the set $\{e,g,g^{-1}\}$ is an element of  $\mathcal{H}$). On the other hand, of course, I was waiting for a non-trivial structure of manifold. In fact, we know that the space of embeddings beetwen two smooth manifolds is an infinite-dimensional smooth manifold. So, I was wondering if we could use this structure of manifold to endow $\mathcal{H}$ of a differentiable structure of manifold